# How can i sum multi dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#

how can i sum multi dimensional array please an easy and understandable example in c#.

I search a lot and find many result but the code is very complex in these articles/examples, so i want that if any of you have easy solution then please post it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give an example of your code (mostly what types you are working with), and your expected results

Comment: It depends on your definition of sum - if you are able to post sample data and expected output, or a clearer description of your desired result, it would be helpful.

Comment: actually i don't have mine, and i am not able to understand the examples i find, so if some one have any easy example code/link then please share....

Comment: Okay - are you handling a multidimensional array or a jagged array? Are you looking for a sum of all the elements or only sums in a particular rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle two-dimensional jagged arrays:

```
var x = new[] { 
    new[] { 77, 32, 6 },
    new[] { 4, 6, 8 },
    new[] { 45, 2 } };

int sum = x.SelectMany(a => a).Sum();
```

The `SelectMany` operator flattens your inner arrays into an outer sequence, whose sum you can then compute.